# BigDecimal setScale using rounding mode half even not working

Tags: java, rounding, currency, bigdecimal

Someone please tell me the mistake I did:

I have the number: 225.0453 which internally is saved with 4 digits. This is a USD currency number that i want pretty print for displaying. I use `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`

As USD uses 2 fraction digits the half even rounded number should be $225.04. But i get $225.05.

This is my code (i changed it to create a MWE):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Currency cur = Currency.getInstance("USD");
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal("225.0453");
    result = result.setScale(cur.getDefaultFractionDigits(),RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    nf.setCurrency(cur);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(cur.getDefaultFractionDigits());
    return nf.format(result.doubleValue());
}
```

In addition i will also be greatful for a better solution as this seems not quite right. (I tried `nf.setRoundingMode` but that did not work at all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`RoundingMode` `HALF_EVEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) rounds toward the even neighbor only when the value is equidistant between possible rounding targets.

> Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.

This means that it would have rounded down if the amount was 225.045, the equidistant value.  But because your amount of 225.0453 was greater than the equidistant value, it will still round up.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know/realize that it takes less significant fraction digits into account. Which still leaves me with the problem that my account statement for that transaction is 225.04 and my (i guess more precise calculation) returns 225.05. I guess i need to flaten the digits before pretty printing then. Thank you anyway. Correct answer

Comment: @Dennis It takes the full value of the number into account. Why would you ever want 225.0453 rounded to 225.04 when it's closer to 225.05?

Comment: It does make sense. I guess my school knowledge got the best of me..i remember learning something along the lines "if you want to round to 2 fraction digits look at the third, is it below 5 round down is it 5 or more round up" ... of course this still holds if you look atmore fraction digits...only the half_even rouding mode i run into an edge case that does not hold true by only looking at the next digit. Thank you for pointing that out